# Nesting anonymous delegates in C# - how to make code maintainable and readable?

Tags: c#, coding-style, refactoring

I'm making a game, and it may have modal UI windows, like popover windows.
I encapsulated all the fiddling into my class and I just call one method to show such window on screen, for example a method to show a list of characters:

```
ShowCharactersTable(List<Character>list, 
    Action<Character>didSelectCharacter, Action<bool>didCancel)
```

Example in use:

```
ShowCharactersTable(someList, delegate(Character selectedCharacter) {

// code that runs after you picked a character

, delegate(bool didCancel){

// code that runs after you cancelled selection

});
```

This is fine. Everything is transparent and easy to use. But I get into trouble as soon as I need to nest this. For example, on character list I have few buttons on each character cell, so I need to provide delegates for that. This gets complicated. I also might need to show another modal window on top of that, with a call like this:

```
ShowActivitySelector(List<Activity>activitiesToShow,
     Action<Activity>didSelectActivity,   
     Action<bool>didCancelPickingActivity);
```

And when I select activity I might need to show Alert if something goes wrong, like here:

```
ShowAlert(string alertText, Activity<bool>didAccept,
          Activity<bool>didCancel);
```

So now, to call a simple table of characters I need to write a 3 page long method with nested delegates. Does not sound like fun. How can I modularize this and make easier/more maintainable?

I don't want to couple my interface to my model, as I will need to show those lists, selectors and alerts from many different parts of my game with different parameters.
How can this be fixed and what do I do about this?

Comment: MVVM and wpf [data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) should do the trick. You should not define all delegates in one ViewModel. Each View has its own ViewModel and only ViewModels has to communicate between each other. E.g. if same window can be invoked from different places, then that means there are ViewModels for *places*, but they invoke same instance of ViewModel to display that window.

Comment: You need to analyze your program in depth. Refactor, use design pattern. Think of attaching event whenver you need.

Comment: I would use events for this and then you can attach subscribers to them or if the code can be threaded you can task this stuff, allowing for continuations should there need to be any follow up. I would also think about the single responsibility principle here, by nesting all this functionality the thing at the root is not longer performing 1 task ... or is it? we can't be sure! This will add obscurity as your game grows.